# Evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{n}{n^3+1}+\frac{2n}{n^3+2}+ \dots + \frac{n^2}{n^3+n}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Compute the limit:
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{n}{n^3+1}+\frac{2n}{n^3+2}+ \dots + \frac{n^2}{n^3+n}\right)$$

I tried applying the sandwich rule, constructing an upper and lower bound for the sequence, but I can't get the bounds to have the same limit.

Hints?

Comment: So the sum you're calculating is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k \cdot n}{n^3+k} = n \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^3 + k} 
$$
Perhaps that is easier to calculate. Notice that $n^3$ is essentially a constant in the summation.

Comment: Think about harmonic numbers

Comment: I've been trying different things, but it diverges in the end.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, it's $n$ *cubed* in the denominator, not $n$ squared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S_n = \frac{n}{n^3+1}+\frac{2n}{n^3+2}+ \dots + \frac{n^2}{n^3+n}$

The $k^{th}$ term = $t_k = \frac{kn}{n^3+k} \leq \frac{kn}{n^3} = \frac{k}{n^2}$, $\forall{k} \geq 1$

Then, $S_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}t_k \leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k=\frac{1}{n^2}.\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}=U_n$ (let), $\forall{n} \in \mathcal{N}$

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} U_n = \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} S_n \leq \frac{1}{2}$.

Also, we have, $t_k = \frac{kn}{n^3+k} \geq \frac{kn}{n^3+n} = \frac{k}{n^2+1}$, $\forall{k} \leq n$

Again, $S_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}t_k \geq \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n^2+1} = \frac{1}{n^2+1}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k=\frac{1}{n^2+1}.\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}.\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}=V_n$ (let), $\forall{n} \in \mathcal{N}$

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} V_n = \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} S_n \geq \frac{1}{2}$.

Hence, we have sandwich, $U_n \geq S_n \geq V_n$, $\forall{n} \in \mathcal{N}$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} U_n=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} V_n=\frac{1}{2}$.

The next figure shows the convergence:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\frac{n^2(n+1)}{2(n^3+n)}=\frac{n}{n^3 +n } +...+\frac{n^2}{n^3 +n }\leq \frac{n}{n^3 +1 } +...+\frac{n^2}{n^3 +n }\leq \frac{n}{n^3 +1 } +...+\frac{n^2}{n^3 +1 }=\frac{n^2(n+1)}{2(n^3+1)}$$